# How to check in this case if the linked list has loops or not

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list

Have to create a linked list where we will add up departments which are dependent on each other or not .

input will be department name , followed by department name on which they are dependent , some can have followed by empty strings that means they don't depend on any department .

So will output will be the second  department at first and so on

1. one department can not depend on it self (taken care)
2. have to find if the department having cyclic dependency (problem)

### input

sales

marketing accounts

finance sales

### so output will be

sales finance  accounts marketing

**input**

sales marketing

marketing accounts

accounts sales

**output**

error it can not have cyclic dependency

tried with below codes to see if my linked list has loops

```
private bool DoesItHasLoops()
        {
            var fast = myLinkedList.First;
            var slow = myLinkedList.First;
            while (fast != null && fast.Next != null)
            {
                fast = fast.Next.Next;
                slow = slow.Next;
                if (slow == fast)
                    return true;


            }
            return false;
        }
```

its not working and not able to find the loop .

Below code is the way I am adding strings in my linked list .

```
private LinkedList<strings> myLinkedList;

public void AddDepartments(string[] input)
{
   if (input.Count() > 1)
      {
        if (myLinkedList.Contains(input[0]))  
         {

          myLinkedList.AddBefore(adjList.Find(input[0]), input[1]);

          }
        else
         {
          myLinkedList.AddLast(input[1]);                            
          myLinkedList.AddLast(input[0]);
         }
      }
    else
    {
     myLinkedList.AddLast(input[0]);
     myLinkedList.AddLast(string.empty());

     }
}
```

this is working for all the cases only the cyclic case its not working

Comment: In your first example shouldn't it be 'sales finance, accounts marketing'? If not, I'm not sure I understand the order

Comment: yes , my mistake editing

Comment: Can a department have multiple dependencies?

Comment: It might be having multiple dependencies

Comment: @Mainak Ganguly It would be nice if you could tell us what approach you ended up using and selecting an answer for your question as you have two good versions of how to solve your problem. Or if you came up with something yourself post it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change your architecture a bit. Instead of using this construct where everything is stored in a `LinkedList`, I'd go with a `Dictionary`. This way you can easily connect the department with the department its depending on.

So you would have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key is the department and the value the departments it depends on:

```
private bool DoesItHasLoops(Dictionary<string, List<string>> departmentWithDepending)
{
    HashSet<string> checkedDepartments = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach (var department in departmentWithDepending)
    {
        checkedDepartments.Add(department.Key);
        if (HasConflict(department.Value, departmentWithDepending, checkedDepartments))
        {
            return true;
        }
        checkedDepartments.Clear();
    }
    return false;
}

private bool HasConflict(List<string> dependentDepartments,
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> departmentWithDepending,
    HashSet<string> checkedDepartments)
{
    foreach (var currentDepartment in dependentDepartments)
    {
        //Checks if this department was already checked, if yes you got a loop
        if (checkedDepartments.Contains(currentDepartment))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Checks if the current department has a dependency
            if (departmentWithDepending.ContainsKey(currentDepartment))
            {
                //marks the current department as checked and and checks if the department the current department depends on has any conflicts(loops)
                checkedDepartments.Add(currentDepartment);
                if (HasConflict(departmentWithDepending[currentDepartment], departmentWithDepending, checkedDepartments))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    checkedDepartments.Remove(currentDepartment);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Finding these kinds of loops isn't that easy, the approach above hopefully works, I haven't tested it yet. If you have any questions you can ask in the comment section as I could see why this code might be difficult to grasp.

Btw I'm calling HasConflict(...) from within itself to find any next conflicts. Normally I'd advice to not do this as you can get an infinite loop. You should only do this if you are 100% certain that there is no way it can get stuck.

Edit:

```
departments: a, b, c, d

dependencies:
a (depends on) b, c
b (depends on) (nothing)
c (depends on) d
d (depends on) a, b

dependencies that are fine:
a -> b 
a -> c -> d -> b
c -> d -> b
d -> b

dependencies that would cause a conflict:
a -> c -> d -> a
c -> d -> a -> c
d -> a -> c -> d
```

Comment: You say you would use a Dictionary, what if a department is dependent on multiple departments? You wouldn't be able to have duplicate keys.

Comment: @sr28 If you read the code carefully you see that the department that is dependent is the key and the department it depends on the value, so there would not be any key conflicts. Also the author didn't mention that there could be multiple dependencies. If that's the case you would have to change the code and have a List<string> as value.

Comment: Yes, your code assumes that no other department can be dependent on the same department. So 'sales' for example can only ever have 1 department dependent on it. Sounds unrealistic as I can assume most departments will be dependent on accounts for example

Comment: I agree with Mirko Brandt. Multiple dependency can be there.

Comment: I edited the code so that one department can have multiple dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the easiest way to identify these loops is to find those where a department with a dependency is also listed as the dependency itself at some point and run through the chain of dependencies in between to see if they connect. That said, your architecture seems a bit off. I'd create an object to hold the department and it's list of dependencies as a well as a flag as to whether it has circular references like this:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Dependencies { get; set; }
    public bool HasCircularReferences { get; set; } 
}
```

You then pass in a list of Departments and iterate over each of them and find the other departments that have that department listed as a dependency. You then work back from those through the chain of dependencies to see if you end up getting back to the current department. You can use a loop like this (note this is a static method as I was testing it in a Console app):

```
private static void GetDependents(IList<int> dependencies, int seed)
{
    foreach (var dependent in dependencies)
    {
        var dependentDept = departments.Where(d => d.Id == dependent).FirstOrDefault();
        if (dependentDept.Dependencies.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dependencies.Contains(seed) || dependentDept.HasCircularReferences)
            {
                SetCircularReferenceFlag(seed, true);
                break;
            }
            GetDependents(dependentDept.Dependencies, seed);
        }
        else
        {
            SetCircularReferenceFlag(seed, false);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This sets the HasCircularReferences flag on the department using the SetCircularReferenceFlag method which is:

```
private static void SetCircularReferenceFlag(int departmentId, bool hasCircularReferences)
{
    var seedDept = departments.Where(d => d.Id == departmentId).FirstOrDefault();
    seedDept.HasCircularReferences = hasCircularReferences;
}
```

The GetDependents method can then be called for each department in your list like this:

```
foreach (var department in departments)
{
    GetDependents(department.Dependencies, department.Id);
}
```

Departments has been set to look like this using the Department object defined above:

```
private static List<Department> departments = new List<Department>
{
    new Department
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "sales",
        Dependencies = new List<int>{ 2 }
    },
    new Department
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "accounts",
        Dependencies = new List<int>{ 3 }
    },
    new Department
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "marketing",
        Dependencies = new List<int>{ 1 }
     },
     new Department
     {
        Id = 4,
        Name = "finance",
        Dependencies = new List<int>{ 1 }
     }
 };
```

When running this through a console app you get the following results:

[image]

Comment: `if (dependencies.Contains(seed) || dependentDept.HasCircularReferences)` I don't understand this part, why are you iterating over dependencies and everytime check if dependencies contains the seed?

Comment: The seed refers to the department you're checking the original department list. If a dependency contains this then it must have a circular reference. Equally, if a department (seed) has dependency on a department, which itself has a circular reference, then the current department (seed) must also have a circular reference

Comment: I understand your thought process, I just don't understand why you do `if(dependencies.Contains(seed))` inside the loop as neither the seed nor the dependencies will change inside the loop. Wouldn't it make more sense to check for that outside the loop?

Comment: I could take dependencies.Contains(seed) out of the loop but I'm making the use of the dependentDept.Dependencies.Count > 0 check, to make sure I don't do this unless I need to. I would also need another call to set the flag on top of the 2 I have so far if I did this